# How to start android tablet preview in Mobile First Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

In Mobile First Console, how to start android tablet preview.

After building app and running on preview mode, by default android phone emulator is displayed. I want android tablet emulator to be previewed by default.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the default "skin". You can only select it after previewing the application's web resources.